# Oval progress bar || pie chart

Tags: html, css, progress-bar, pie-chart

How to create regulated oval progress bar using only HTML&CSS?

[image: need to create like this one]

[My jsfiddle try](https://jsfiddle.net/51wmxLek/) works but looks different (without inside\outside border or padding)

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 64 64" class="pie">
   <circle class="background" r="25%" cx="50%" cy="50%"></circle>
   <circle class="chart" r="25%" cx="50%" cy="50%" stroke-dasharray="85 100"></circle>
</svg>
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by that it looks different?

Comment: My variant without inside and outside border.

Comment: Is there best way to regulate progress percentage without stroke-dasharray? Because its not work correct, example: https://jsfiddle.net/sboe73ft/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what youre looking for but cant hurt looking right?

So here is my example:
https://jsfiddle.net/b3h0tqye/57/

I simply changed the following lines:

```
<circle class="background" r="27%" cx="50%" cy="50%" style="stroke-width:1;"></circle>
 <circle class="background" r="22%" cx="50%" cy="50%" style="stroke-width:1;"></circle>
```